# erro ao renderizar Polyline react leaflet

Tags: react, leaflet

alguém sabe como resolver esse problema de renderização do Polyline no leaflet ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu MapContainer renderiza um Polyline de acordo com uma lista de cordenadas, no entando, de acordo com o zoom ao movimentar o mapa a area que cobre o meu poligno fica dessa forma.

Essas são as propriedades que eu uso para monta-lo.

```
export default function MapPolyline(props: InputProps) {
      const { color = '#0071a9', positions, show = true } = props;
    
      if (!positions || !show) return null;
    
      return (
        <Polyline
          pathOptions={{ color, fill: true, fillColor: color }}
          positions={positions}
        />
      );
    }
```

Hora ou outra acontece ainda de o fill que cobre a área ser mostrada fora dos dominos do meu poligno, como na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe, ou poderia me dar uma direção de como resolver esse problema ?

att .

Answer (score -2):

Eu consegui resolver meu problema alterando completamente o componente responsável por montar a área informada.

A alteração consiste em mudar o Polyline por Polygon.

Dessa forma meu código ficou assim:

```
export default function MapPolyline(props: InputProps) {
      const { color = '#0071a9', positions, show = true } = props;
    
      if (!positions || !show) return null;
    
      return <Polygon pathOptions={{ color, fill: true, fillColor: color }} positions={positions} />;
    }
```

Ambos são importados de dentro do mesmo pacote:

```
import { Polygon } from 'react-leaflet';
```